# Master Detail not showing details table in modal popup - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, crud, master-detail

I am doing CRUD operations on a Master Detail models Team and TeamMember using modal popup. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057686/asp-net-core-mvc-master-detail-in-partial-view) to perform the Create operation and it is ok, now i am doing the Detail operation:

TeamController:

```
public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        Team team = _dbcontext.Team
            .Include(a => a.TeamMembers)
            .Where(e => e.TeamId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_DetailTeamPartialView", team);
    }
```

Index.cshtml detail button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@("#DetailTeam-"+item.TeamId)" data-url="@Url.Action($"Detail/{item.TeamId}")">Detail</button>
@await Html.PartialAsync("_DetailTeamPartialView", item)
```

_DetailTeamPartialView.cshtml:

```
    @model Team

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_DetailTeamPartialView";
}
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="@("DetailTeam-"+Model.TeamId)" aria-labelledby="DetailTeamLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Detail Team</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamName)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TeamName)
                    </dd>
                    .......

                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamMembers)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Member name</th>
                                    <th>Birth date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input asp-for="@Model.TeamMembers[i].MemberName" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input asp-for="@Model.TeamMembers[i].BirthDate" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                        </td>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code displays only team details and doesn't show the TeamMember details. Any help??

**EDIT**
these are the classes:

```
public class Team
{
    
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
   
    [Required]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; } = new List<TeamMember>();       
}
public class TeamMember
{
    

    [Key]
    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string MemberName{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team{ get; set; }        
}
```

'Model.TeamMembers.Count' in '@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)' return 0 why??

Comment: Well, I've seen you are are passing `stock` here `return PartialView("_DetailTeamPartialView", stock);` it should be `team/team member` . In addition, what does `Team team = _dbcontext.Team`  consists? Does it contains `team member`? Could you please share the class details?

Comment: I added the classes please check the post

Comment: Thanks for shareing, have you checked this line `return PartialView("_DetailTeamPartialView", stock);`. What happend if you replace `stock` with `team`? does that produce correct result?

Comment: Yes it was just a mistake while posting the question, i replace it with team and the same problem persists. still showing just team details.

Comment: 'Model.TeamMembers.Count' in '@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)' return 0 why??

Comment: Did you missed any relevant code being shared here? Some snippet are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Master Detail not showing details table in modal popup - ASP.NET Core

I have gone through your shared `code snippet` between the line altough, you haven't shared your `index` page's code that certainly playing important role here. Nontheless, I tried to visualize what you are trying to achieve.

**Expected Behaviour:**

[image]

From the shared code, I have managed to build above output therefore, the expected behaviour might be while clicking on `details button` on the `team's` list which is the `index page` should display the `details list` of all the `team member` of that `particular team`. If that is the business scenario, then I would say, your approach were wrong and you are doing mess of course here thus, follow the steps below which will help to resolve your issue.

**Database:**

[image]

**Note:** Models would be same as yours. So not repeating that part.

**Controller:**

```cs
public class TeamController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;


        public TeamController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _environment = environment;
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var teamList = _context.Teams.Include(a => a.TeamMembers).ToList();
            return View(teamList);
        }
        
    }
```

**Note:** You are doing the mess here as you are using another `details` `action` for the `_DetailTeamPartialView` which is complete Irelevant here. Only `Index` action is capable here what you are trying to achieve. Just need to use `Include(a => a.TeamMembers)` which the action.

**View Of Index()**

```cs
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Team>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamName)
            </th>
            <th>
                Member Details
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="@("#DetailTeam-"+item.TeamId)">Detail</button>
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_DetailTeamPartialView", item)
                </td>
     
            </tr>
           
           
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**_DetailTeamPartialView**

Though, your `_DetailTeamPartialView` is alrigh and no vital issue has not seen,

```cs
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Team

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_DetailTeamPartialView";
}
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="@("DetailTeam-"+Model.TeamId)" aria-labelledby="DetailTeamLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Detail Team</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>

                <dl class="row">
                    <div style="margin-left:10px">
                        <dt class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamName)
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TeamName)
                        </dd>
                        .......

                        <dt class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamMembers)
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-10">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Member name</th>
                                        <th>Birth date</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input asp-for="@Model.TeamMembers[i].MemberName" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input asp-for="@Model.TeamMembers[i].BirthDate" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly />
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    }

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </dd>
                    </div>

                </dl>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Takeaways:**

As you are using `HTML Tag helper class` that is `@await Html.PartialAsync("_DetailTeamPartialView", item)` so you don't need to use below `Detail action` on your `controller`. `Index` action would handled the `_DetailTeamPartialView` autometically.

```cs
public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        Team team = _dbcontext.Team
            .Include(a => a.TeamMembers)
            .Where(e => e.TeamId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_DetailTeamPartialView", team);
    }
```

Comment: I was missing to add Include(a => a.TeamMembers) to Index action, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to assist you on this.